# call method on every object from the same class

Tags: c++, oop, object, arduino

I'm working on a arduino project.

For those who don't know what a arduino is:

arduino is a little electronic-board whit a micro-controller which can be programmed in C++

Since a arduino is a little micro-controller, it is single core 16MHz multiprocessing is very hard.

I have made a class, in th constructor, it defines a pin as pwm output en sets min fade, max fade, fade time etc.

I have methods to start fading and stop fading change setpoint, speed...

for multifading I've made a update method.

So when I call light1.update() it checks if the pwm output needs to be changed or not.

**Now the question is:**

I have more lights so that will be:

```
light1.update();
light2.update();
light3.update();
and so on
```

Is there a way to write just one line to call update() on every object of the fade class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a combination of the **Observer pattern** combined with an **Instance manager** pattern.

Whenever you create a new instance of `Light`, add it to the manager. When you want the events to be triggered, iterate through the instances in the manager and call `update`.

Something like:

```
class LightManager
{
    static std::vector<Light> lights;
    static void notify()
    {
       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < lights.size() ; i++ )
           lights[i].update();
    }
    static void add(const light& l)
    {
       lights.push_back(l);
    }
};

class Light
{
    Light()
    {
       LightManager::add(*this);
    }
};
```

Then you update all lights with:

```
LightManager::notify();
```

Comment: thanks for reply

but arduino / avr-gcc doesn't have any vectors or something similar
this is a good solution for regular os (linux/unix).

Comment: i has something in mind like this, but doesn't how make a variable array for storing objects, vectors is probably the only proper way to do that.

Comment: @on8tom well, you can use C-style arrays.